# Django: Customizing Display Behavior of ModelForms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have this Model:

```
class DistList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)  
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have this ModelForm (using crispy-forms)

```
class DistListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DistList
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'members', 'is_private']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DistListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)   
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Field('name', css_class='form-control'),
                Field('description', css_class='form-control'),
                Field('members',css_class='form-control'),
         )
        self.fields['is_private'].label = 'Private Distribution List'
```

What I'd like to do is change the multi-select that gets rendered to something like what github uses to add users to repos.  There's an input box below a ul, the user types in the name of the user, hits add, and the new user gets dynamically added as an li on the ul.  I'm good with the javascript/jquery side of it but it seems like ModelForms aren't meant to be modified like this.

My question is more conceptual or best practice I suppose.  If I want to alter the behavior of a ModelForm so substantially, is it best to just make a Form and deal with it that way?  What's the "Djangoest" way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to keep the HTML outpot of the original `<select>` widget, and only hide/replace it using your JavaScript code. Any time the user changes the selection in your fancy widget, the underlying `<select>` should be changed accordingly.

This way, you get graceful degradation for free, and it works independently from any underlying backend. If I'm not mistaken, the `filter_{horizontal,vertical}` widgets in the Django admin work this way; maybe you can [look at the widget code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L21) to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you are making substantial changes to the form's functionality. Most of the changes you mentioned are happening at the templates or presentation layer. Django maintains a clear separation between the models, views and templates. So, there is nothing wrong with using ModelForms and making the necessary modifications.